# Is $lim_{x \to a}\int_{g(x)}^{h(x)}f(t)dt$, where $g(a) = h(a)$, always equal to $0$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits

I don't know how to handle such limits. I feel like it should always be equal to $0$, and that's what wolfram alpha says for examples I find, but I'm not sure. I would feel much more secure if someone could either prove that it's the case, or prove what conditions $f$ must satisfy for it to be true.

I have two examples:
$$lim_{x \to 0}\int_{x^3}^{x^4}\sin(t^2)dt$$
And
$$lim_{x \to 0}\int_{0}^{\sin(x^2)}e^{t^2}dt $$

Comment: $g(x) = x,\, h(x) = 2x, f(t) = \frac{1}{t}$. If $f$ is integrable, the limit is $0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer what do you mean, isn't $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ integrable to $\ln|x| + C$?

Comment: It's not integrable at $0$, $\lim\limits_{\epsilon \searrow 0} \int_\epsilon^1 \frac{dt}{t} = +\infty$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If:

$h, g$ are continuous at $a$

and

$f$ is integrable in some $[a,a+\epsilon]$

What you said is true.

For that, define: $F(x)=\int_{[a,x]}f \quad$; $G=F \circ g \quad$; $H=F \circ h$. By the fundamental theorem of calculus, $F$ is continuous and so are $G$ and $H$. Since your integral is $H-G$ and $H(a)=G(a)=0$, you have your result.

For $f$ not integrable, the comment of Daniel Fischer is an example that it is not true.

For $g$ or $h$ not continuous, just take $f=1$, $g(x)=1$ for $x>0$, $h=0$ and $g(0)=0$.